# Custom Vertex type [graphs] containing list of adjacent vertices: incomplete type error

Tags: c++, graph

I'm implementing my own set of classes for representing graphs. I'm new to C++, so I'm having some trouble with pointers. You see, this was my original code:

```
class Vertex {
 public:
    int label;
    Vertex adjacent_vertices[];
    Vertex(int l) : label(l) { }
    Vertex(int l, Vertex adjacents[]) : label(l), adjacent_vertices(adjacents) { }
};
```

but then I get an incomplete type error. From my research, I apparently need to use a list of pointers for `adjacent_vertices`. `Vertex* adjacent_vertices[];` But then there's a problem with the second constructor. None of these worked:

```
adjacent_vertices(*adjacents)
adjacent_vertices(adjacents*)
adjacent_vertices(&adjacents)
```

Is there a better way to implement this? I feel like there's something very obvious I'm missing here, as a Java/Python dev who's never worked with pointers before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution would be to use vector for your adjacent_vertices.

```
class Vertex {
public:
    int label;
    vector<Vertex> adjacent_vertices;
    Vertex(int l) : label(l) { }
    Vertex(int l, vector<Vertex> adjacents) : label(l), adjacent_vertices(adjacents) { }
};
```

Comment: This answer worked for me, but I had to make a modification: adding the dereference operator: `adjacent_vertices(*adjacents)`. The code in the answer doesn't compile.

Comment: The code as it is compiles for me fine.
can you show the complete last line of you code as it is now?
I don't see why you would need to differentiate it.

Comment: [Here's](https://gist.github.com/CrazyPython/1f4b7671ff36ea1c7aae247ce109d34c) the gist. I compiled it with everything else commented out. I'm using C++11 by the way.

Comment: Never mind that. I left `[]` behind by accident. That's why I got that. I'm dumb for doing that.